# Twitter Acess Token error - Authorize "" to use your account?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to create an app on twitter. And when i login it gives me the following error -

Error- **Authorize "" to use your account**?

and i am getting following error in access request token (https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token)-

Error -**Failed to validate oauth signature and token**.

what i am doing is redirecting the user to:

**https://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token={$token}**

Please help what to do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets

Comment: And More details regarding the integration of twitter with share kit visit reference link here http://bit.ly/IOwVeX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you created the app on twitter without callback url, and in under settings its "Read, Write and Access direct messages".

follow these steps -

1) Create a new app on twitter without a callback url
2) After creating the app go to settings and set the access level to third radio button (Read, Write and Access direct messages)
3) download this project - https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine and check in this project.
4) if the step 3 working then try to integrate this in your project

Comment: Thanks, Now it working, i was creating the app with callback url -https://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token={$token}.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define TwitterConsumerKey    @"Your app Consumer key"

#define TwitterSecretKey      @"Your app secret key"

#define TwitterCallbackUrl    @"Your app call back url which is inserted into the twitter app while created app"
```

Apply this it may be solve your problems.

Answer (score 1):

These problem/error is generate......please check

1)your Consumer Key and Consumer Secret key

2)check your device time Zone(timestamp) means correct time

```
Click on the clock and then "Date & Time preferences" -Check "Set date and time automatically with: Apple Americas/U.S. (time.apple.com)"
```

3)replace it in SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.m file

```
self.requestTokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token"];
self.accessTokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://twitter.com/oauth/access_token"];
self.authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize"];
```

Comment: I have changed- the date and time automatically with: Apple Americas/U.S. but it is still not solved -giving this error -The request token for this page is invalid. it may have already been used, or expired because it is too old. Please go back to the site or application that sent you here and try again; it was probably just a mistake.

Comment: I am using the same URLs (with https instead of http), don't no where is the problem.

Comment: clean your build , derived data and delete from device and again run

Comment: go to bulid setting and search  for the “Header Search Paths” and set usr/include/libxml2

Comment: i was creating the app with callback url -twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token={$token}.I should leave that field blank.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define kOAuthConsumerKey @"place your account consumer key"
#define kOAuthConsumerSecret @"place your authorized consumer secret key"
```

This will get when we login to twitter as twitter developer with your normal account.Create these keys,secret key in twitter account and work in your app.

Comment: Keys are already set. This error is not about missing something in coding, The app that i have created on twitter is not authorized. it says "Authorize "" to use your account?" after pressing "authorize app" button.

Comment: I also got same error when I worked in my app with the twitter.U cross check your keys.

Comment: We will get 6 letter number token to get authorized.Did u get this.

Comment: No i didn't get any 6 letter number token. it is a long alpha numeric access token.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9955/discussion-between-s-rama-rao-and-naina-soni)